# How to add value to array using a FOR loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
---This API will break the string RESULT__ in each (^) 
resultado := lmw_base_util_api.Get_MV_Field(RESULT__,'^',A);

----WHICH ARE 7 OF THIS (^) - 1 = 6 WORDS IN THE RESULT__ STRING,
--- WHICH ARE:  All_Equipm    Consulting    DITCHCLEANER    Friction_M    JUAN    LUIS   = 6
NUMBER_ELEMENTS := NUMBER_DEVISION_ - 1;
```

I have the following script:

```
DECLARE
RESULT__ varchar2(100) :='^All_Equipm^Consulting^DITCHCLEANER^Friction_M^JUAN^LUIS^';
NUMBER_DEVISION_ NUMBER ;
resultado VARCHAR2(400);

---This cursor will give me the number of elements in the string
CURSOR GET_NUMBER_DEVISION IS
select lmw_base_util_api.Get_DCount(RESULT__,'^') AS NUMBER_DEVISION from dual;

BEGIN

FOR REC IN GET_NUMBER_DEVISION LOOP
   NUMBER_DEVISION_ := REC.NUMBER_DEVISION;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(NUMBER_DEVISION_);
        FOR A IN 1 .. NUMBER_DEVISION_ LOOP
          resultado := lmw_base_util_api.Get_MV_Field(RESULT__,'^',A);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(resultado);
         END LOOP;
END LOOP;


END;
```

How can I store each value of resultado in an ARRAY?
Also, I would like to use the value outside of the For loop because I need to separate each by (,) 
My result needs to be:

All_Equipm,Consulting,DITCHCLEANER,Friction_M,JUAN,LUIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a loop nor an array. All you need is to replace the character '^' with a comma. The only issue is whether there is a leading comma or not. I sugest you see Oracle documentation for functions. In this case SUBSTR and REPLACE.

```
select case when substr(res,1,1) = ','
            then substr(res,2)
            else res
       end resultado
 from (select replace('^All_Equipm^Consulting^DITCHCLEANER^Friction_M^JUAN^LUIS^' ,'^',',') res  from dual)
```